# Error in read.table: !header: invalid argument type

Tags: r, read.table

I am having the strangest of issues. The following code no longer works:

```
Test<-matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3)
 colnames(Test)<-c("a","b","c")
 write.table(Test,file="Test.txt")
 d<-read.table("Test.txt",header=T)
```

I get:

> Error in !header: invalid argument type

I tried rebooting R, it didn't help.

Comment: Works fine with me, could you try `read.delim` if you get the same error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check `class(T)`. Most likely `T` was overwritten with a non-boolean value. Restart of R probably loads the saved session.

Comment: As Oleg indicates, cleaning up your `.Rhistory` may be necessary.

Comment: In my case `F` was overwritten by 
`function (x, n = 1, ...) 
UseMethod("F")`

I used the full form `FALSE` as a quick fix